# Tomcat JNDI PSQLException: This connection has been closed

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, tomcat, grails

We've deployed several apps that run in the same tomcat container, and connect to our postgresql database through a JNDI lookup. Here's the sanitized config (`server.xml`):

```
<Resource name="MyDataSource" 
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" 
    url="jdbc:postgresql://myrdsinstance.com:5432/MyDatabase"
    username="my_username"
    password="my_password" />
```

This was running fine for months, but this morning any attempt at reading the DB failed:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:843)
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.getAutoCommit(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:804)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1079.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:80)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.getAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:68)
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1309)
org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:57)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:70)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:59)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:377)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
```

The temporary fix was to restart the `tomcat7` service, which I assume re-opened the closed DB connection. But now I'm investigating the root cause and hopefully a long-term fix. I found from `catalina.out`:

```
2015-02-09 14:15:55,260 WARN [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08003
```

From [the PostgreSQL error codes doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html) I see that it means `connection_does_not_exist`.

I've done some Googling and couldn't find much relating to this exact problem. I would think that if a connection is closed it would be handled by JDBC, Hibernate, or even GORM (for the grails apps). Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1):

Examining the code for `BasicDataSource` in `commons-dbcp`, I've come to the conclusion that by specifying a `validationQuery` as a property of the data source we're allowing the container to verify that the connection is valid before it ever reaches our code. Of course there still is a small chance that the connection becomes invalid between when it is validated by tomcat and when it reaches our code, so this solution is not ideal. In short though:

```
<Resource name="MyDataSource" 
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" 
    url="jdbc:postgresql://myrdsinstance.com:5432/MyDatabase"
    username="my_username"
    password="my_password"
    validationQuery="SELECT 1" />
```

Hopefully there's a better solution than this, but I figured I'd post what we did for any other googlers out there.